# How to manage POD object between other objects?

Tags: c++, oop

This is for a basic scientific calculation program and I am relatively new to c++.

So let's say I have a data class. (It mainly just holds data apart from one time when it reads it from a file).
And a simple representation is this:

```
class Data {
 public:
    Data(string filename){/*some stuff*/};
    double data(){return data_;};
    void GetDataFromFile();
 private:
    double data_;
};
```

I have some main code that sets the process going, which might look like this:

```
datastuff = std::unique_ptr<Data>(new Data(filestring));
```

I am using a unique ptr because I dont want to have to worry about delete, and the lifetime of the data is tied to this datastuff variable in this main bit of code (datastuff is a class member variable).
And lots of objects that want to read what that data is in order to perform operations.

The question is, how do I let the other classes/objects get access to this data?
Should it be for example this:

```
class Solve {
 private:
    Data* data_
 public:
    void DataIn(Data* d){data_ = d;};
};
```

with a call like:

```
solve.DataIn(datastuff.get());
```

Is that correct?

Note that I have a lot of objects like "solve", and they all need to be able to look at the same data.

Also - I do not want any of them to be able to modify the data. So should I be taking a different approach?

Edit: based on comments below trying to make example a bit clearer

Comment: Why do you need the pointers at all?

Comment: Another way to avoid worrying about deleting things is to not use pointers at all. Have you considered that? You can still pass a pointer to others using `&`, or do it by reference.

Comment: how about struct and function? Life doesn't have to so complicated.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ok that is true. I will probably consider that option. However in the future I may have a lot of these data objects which may be stored as a vector of objects (therefore a vector of pointers?) and so I wanted to do the pointer way so i can easily extend

Comment: @molbdnilo see my above comment

Comment: @windenergy You don't need pointers in collections either, unless you want to go polymorphic (and you won't, if it's just a POD sturcture as you say).

Comment: @molbdnilo Ok I have issues with not using a pointer. Namely that Data class requires an argument in the constructor (a filename). which is not known when the main class is constructed. Therefore, I cant initialise the data class as a member variable of the main class (which is what i believe is required for it not to be a pointer). Seems like a lot of work to avoid a pointer but if they are really that bad i can look at modifying more code

Comment: Probably you want to use shared_ptr<Data> instead of unique_ptr, and use it wherever you're using Data*

Comment: @Mine, Since the lifetime of the "Data" is tied to my main class, I assumed that unique_ptr would be better, based on what I read on this site.

Comment: @windenergy Finally you're getting to the real reason ;-) There's always the path of the initialization function, but that may make things messier. Pointers aren't bad as such, they just tend to cause more problems than they solve.

Comment: @molbdnilo well yes i guess i'm finding it hard to provide a minimal example that can explain my problem.

Comment: @windenergy It is OK to use shared_ptr in your case, as long as your code using shared_ptr are written correctly. But that's your decision which tool to use.

Comment: @windenergy Actually, since the lifetime is tied to the main class, I wouldn't worry too much about using a raw pointer and then sticking "const" everywhere when passing it around.

Comment: @molbdnilo. For example change the solver member to: Data const * data_ . I.e. a pointer to a constant data object?

Comment: @windenergy Yeah. You can even make it a `Data const * const data;` - it's not supposed to be "re-pointed", right? If it doesn't get trickier than "this object which lives throughout the program owns this thing and takes care of it" you can usually keep it simple and worry about something interesting instead. Smart pointers are very good when your objects' lifetimes are less predictable and/or you want to share or transfer ownership. Otherwise they're mostly annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    std::shared_ptr<Data> data_
```

Ended up being the best choice for this case.

As the project developed I required more interaction with the data, and therefore a more uncertain ownership model.